# Strongly typed Views using ViewModels

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I'm using Entity Framework 5 with MVC 4. I used the DbContext Fluent API to create POCO entities.

Let's say that in a specific View, I need access to two or more entities.

What I typically do is create new folder called ViewModels and create a superclass. Then, I simply copy the POCO entities into this superclass to use it in my View.

However, I was trying to think of a way to take advantage of the scaffolding when adding a Controller & View for the superclass inside that ViewModels folder because now, that folder is not part of the EDMX ORM model which the Model Class (in the window) tries to access and put in the list when the Scaffolding option is set to "MVC Controller with read/write actions and views using Entity Framework".

Obviously, many times you'll need a composite of entities to work with in a View rather than just one.

Is there a way to do this, or is the CRUD simply set up only for one entity per View?

Comment: Scaffolds are exactly that, they are meant to be a generic starting point for you to customize your controller/view. If you find yourself doing the same thing over and over again...you could create your own template/scaffold.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I understand that. But the real question is when creating a scaffold for the Controller, will Visual Studio see the models inside the ViewModels folder (for the scaffolding creation) since it is not connected in any way shape or form with the EDMX file?

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean "will Visual Studio see the models inside the ViewModels folder"? Do you mean will Visual Studio give you intelisense? Because the EDMX does two things, the first is to generate C# source code for each of the database objects you have. Visual Studio can parse that for intelisense info.

Comment: When you generate the POCO entities, they are part of the EDMX file (tt files). The view will be able to properly do the scaffolding because it's directly referencing a POCO entity generated from the EDMX file. However, if you have another folder (ViewModels, for example which is not part of the EDMX generated file) and you put the superclass together with whatever POCO entities you need from the EDMX file, will Visual Studio be able to do the scaffolding looking at that new folder plus the two other POCO classes inside the superclass?

Comment: Scaffolding works on Database First because Database First creates C# object. There is nothing magical about EDMX files and POCO classes. Scaffolding works with C# classes. However it does break down a bit when you it then tries to find an EF context for it...then creates one for your ViewModel classes. You have to unwire up the repository and implement your own mapping to the EF context. To be honest you gain very little by having MVC Scaffolding create your controller. But to reiterate. MVC Scaffolding does not work on EDMX, it works on CLR classes. So YES you can get it to work.

Comment: MVC is NOT an EF tech. MVC is a .net tech...which happens to work well with EF.